Create inter rater reliability on one subject and per item
EDIT: Okay due to confusing information I try to simplify my request. Thank you all for your comments so far.
I try to achieve the following:
A group of instructors in our company. Around 50-60 people have to assess a video scenario. In this video a trainee is showing something and the instructors have to give different competencies (9 in total) a grading. The instructors grade every competency itself from 1 (failed) to 5 (exemplary). If they think they haven‘t seen a certain competency they can grade it with NO (not observed).
So I now have to find out if our instructors grade a certain competency similar or if there are big differences which have to be adresses with an instructor training. The company sets for each scenario and each competency within a „gold standard“. A grading we think is the most appropriate. But this is not fixed, because if all instructors agrre on a different grading compared to the gold standard, thats fine and we may have to change the gold standard.
The important part is to find out, how our instructors agree on a grading for a competency.
With that said the goal is to create a score for each competency which then is compared to a key. For example the Landis Koch Benchmark. Then fuether actions are due or not depending on the score.
I tried different methods like Fleiss‘ Kappa. But that doesn‘t seem to work for just one item (A competency).
Also important is the ability to weight between different gradings. For example. If an instructor grades a competency with a 1, that means the student has failed. Another instructor grades the same competency with a 2, thats passed. Low but passed. So these grades are crucial. Whereas a grade of 4 or 5 does not have such a big impact in the outcome for the trainee. This weight has to be taken into account somehow.
I hope I could clarify my request and goal with it. Here s direct example:
Scenario xy: The instructors grade a competency called Knowledge. Total instructors are 50. 10 are grading a „1“. 30 a grading a „2“ and 10 a „3“. So I want to find out how reliable or agreed the instructors on that competency are in terms of a score.
We have contact to an external company and they do exactly that. They deliver for each competency a score to compare it to the benchmark. But the company is expensive and we want to calculate it by ourself, because we have to integrate it in our management system. So I know somehow it is possible to calculate such a score, but of course they don‘t tell us the exact formula.
Maybe you guys have an idea?
Hope that clears the confusion.

I see lots of issues here but most importantly I am not sure I fully understand why you're thinking of this in terms of “reliability” or looking into all these formulas. There are broader concepts of reliability (say generalizability theory) but you're not trying to adjust the measurement procedure itself. Why wouldn't a simple threshold (less than X% of people under 2) work for your purpose?

I edited the question, maybe that clarifies it a bit. A % under 2 can be good if all instructors agree on the grading of 2. We have to work with them if some grade a 1 and others a 4 or even a 0

Can you explain what the ratings (0,1-5) mean? Is it a grade? A rating? A measure of comprehenson? There also are employees who rate a video? But there are also instructors who grade? This is very unclear (even confusing), and w/o understanding what the ratings mean, who the various actors are and what they do, we will not be able to help you.

Sorry for the confusion. Yes these are gradings from 1 (failed) to 5 (exemplary). 0 means the respective competency was not observed in given scenario. All graders are instructors. They grade a scenario which represents a real life scenario. And we want to see if the instructors are grading a given scenario similar in each competency or are there discrepancies which have to be trained. At the end we need like a score for each competency to grade (there are 9 comptenecies in total) which determines further action.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would recommend editing the question based on your last comments and explain in details the structure of your dataset. For example, I didn't realize there were 9 competencies (that can or cannot be present on each video?) Do you have a “ground truth” or reference value for each video (what the real score should be)? Do all the instructors rate all of the scenarios?

Also what are you trying to evaluate and what could the action be? Add more scenarios? Add more raters? Find some way to reduce the variance between instructors?

In any case, using 0 for something that's qualitatively different is a bad idea no matter what. You're probably better off creating a separate variable and dealing with that separately (but it will reveal that your rating dataset has a lot of missing data).

I tried editing and clarify my original post. You think it is more understandable?
